# Getting started with Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, console

I'm trying to simply play with regular expressions in the console, but I can't.

What am I doing wrong? I'm on python 3.5 I think.

First I tried to use `.replace` on a string object.

then I imported the `re` module, but even that didn't work with `re.sub`

I'm basically at a loss. I just want to experiment with regex so I can learn how to use them.

Can you help me get started?

The code that hasn't worked for me is this:

```
m = "555.555.5555"
mm = m.str.replace(r"'.'","helloworld")
mm
>> 555.555.5555
import re
mm = re.sub(r"'.'","helloworld",m)
mm
>> 555.555.5555
```

p.s.

I have some code here that I was trying to emulate

```
df.CODE.str.replace(r"\A'(E?[V\d]\d\d)(\d*).*", r'\1.\2')
```

so that actually works, but I don't understand why. everything I read about says replace doesn't use regex, that you're supposed to use the `re` module but anyway. I don't understand why it works.

Comment: You've been a member for long enough to know that you shouldn't be posting images of text in questions, and that you should provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your issue.

Comment: thanks, next time I'll do better, but I think this is approapriate

Comment: No. Please do not post images like that. Paste the code, and refer to the code in question using your words.

Comment: I've put the code in that I've tried

Comment: Good.  I've retracted my close vote and downvote.  Posting code as text is an important norm for StackOverflow.  Images often get deleted or end up with new urls thereby screwing up the question for future users.

Comment: The reason `re.sub()` fails is because the pattern.  Pattern `r"'.'"` matches a one single quote followed by any character (that's what the period means in regex) followed by another single quote.  To match a literal `.` you need to escape it so that it is matched literally.  The regex needs to be `r'\.'`.

Comment: Give http://pythex.org a try to learn regular expressions. Then try it in your own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use regular expressions in string replaces - string replace does **not** support regular expressions for that you need to import and use the re or regex library.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = "555.555.5555"
>>> >>> mm = re.sub(r"(\d\d)\.(\d)?", m, "helloworld")
>>> mm
'helloworld'
```

Comment: thank you, but I'm still confused about why it worked in the `df.CODE.str.replace(r"\A'(E?[V\d]\d\d)(\d*).*", r'\1.\2')` line of code where the df is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @LegitStack:  It appears that `df.CODE` object has a reference to an object called `str` that has a `replace()` method that accepts regular expressions.  Since Python strings do not support these semantics, the object referred to by `str` is not a Python string.

Comment: @LegitStack - The object that you are working on in your question is a python string - the example in the comment is a pandas dataframe class member - try `dir()` on both.

Comment: @LegitStack: What does `type(df.CODE.str)` return?

Comment: `str` but when I put type(df) I get `pandas.core.series.Series`

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html